# Enum empty overriding

Tags: java

I have a enum class where I override a method (#proccess), but there are some values ​​like OPT and BST that do not override the method since these are deprecated but users can still use these values since these are used in other classes. My question is if there is any better way to do this/more cleaner?

```
public enum CompilationMode { 
    FASTBUILD {
        @Override
        public void proccess(User user) {
            RootedPath rootedPath = (RootedPath) user.path();
            Compilation.fastBuildCompilate(user, rootedPath);
        }
    },
    DEBUG {
        @Override
        public void proccess(User user) {
            Compilation.debugCompilate(user);
        }
    },
    OPT,
    BS;

    public void doProccess(User user) {
        Preconditions.checkNonNull(user);
        proccess(user);
        user.update();
    }

    protected void proccess(User user) {
        /*empty*/
    }
}
```

Comment: so ... you can call a method of an enum twice, and get different results? I'm not entirely convinced you understand the concept of an enum

Comment: What is "not clean" about the current code?

Comment: @Stultuske Why? The code is pretty expressive, and I dont recall that there is a rule that says that methods on an enum "must" be purely functional in the some "idempotent constant" way.

Comment: The real point here: you are asking us to do a code review. Consider to turn to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, read their help pages carefully, and ask there. Here we help with "code not working"; not with "not happy with working code" (most of the time).

Comment: And honestly: I dont see a big problem with your code. It is clear and precise. The only thing I would do: have the enum implement an **interface**, so that you can pass around instances of of it without impairing your ability to mock values.

Comment: @GhostCat good idea, but if I implement the interface I will be also overriding a empty method for OPT and BS

Comment: Sure. That doesn't help with that.

Comment: One thing which is arguably bad about the current design is that if I add a new enum value I'm not prompted to think about what `process` should do for that value, as there's already a default implementation. Perhaps it should be abstract, and you just have to repeat empty implementations on those values which don't need any behaviour.